# Any plugin or shortcut to copy variable values in eclipse from popup window?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I copy variable values in popup shown below to clipboard ?
Any plugin or keyboard shortcut ( preferred ) suggestion is welcome.

[image: Eclipse]

Imagine if this variable contained 18K values, which is what will my program will do. I certainly cannot debug efficiently in such scenarios.

Comment: I don't think that's possible - the variable could be anything, and not necessarily be representable as text. Out of curiosity, why would you need to copy?

Comment: As I mentioned in OP, the class structure I am using can be very large. I need to debug. Out of curiosity mainly though.

Comment: From the popup, probably not. But how about using the variables or expressions view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenarios with 18k values are certainly not worth debugging. Narrow down your use case to a few values to reproduce the bug or whatever you are looking for.

The question didn't state what popup you are looking at specifically but I assume it is the *Inspect Variable* popup (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>).

[image]

If so, you can select the text in the lower area (org.eclipse.team... in the example screenshot) and copy (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) it to the clipboard.

Objects in the *Inspect* view are represented though their `toString()` method. You can override this representation with the *Detail Formatters*  preference. Go to *Window > Preferences > Java > Debug > Detail Formatters*. Here you can specify a Java code snippet that should be evaluated to display instances of a certain class.

Comment: You are right that I should narrow down my test case to a few values to check the pattern. However, such a plugin in itself can be really useful to debug complicated data structures. Perhaps, someone can develop it :)

Comment: As of Feb 11, 2021, on Eclipse IDE 2020-12 (4.18.0), you can easily copy/paste the variables by choosing which nodes to copy (by expanding or collapsing them), selecting them all, then copy/paste them into a text editor. "Nodes" refer to the object you expand in the Variables or Expressions view, such as the `syncName` object node shown in the image in this answer, which is expanded to display `localName` node.